# Does runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) block the main thread even the the coroutine context is not Dispatchers.Main?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning Android with Kotlin and I have learned that the recommended way to start coroutines without blocking the main thread is to do something like below

```
MainScope().launch {
  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // Do IO work here
  }
}
```

But I was also wondering if the call below **not** would block the main thread because it's still using `Dispatchers.IO`

```
runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
  // Do IO work here
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you call `runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO)` from the main-thread, then the main-thread will be blocked while the coroutine finishes on the IO-dispatcher.

This is what the documentation says about this:

> When CoroutineDispatcher is explicitly specified in the context, then
> the new coroutine runs in the context of the specified dispatcher
> while the current thread is blocked. If the specified dispatcher is an
> event loop of another runBlocking, then this invocation uses the outer
> event loop.

You can find the documentation here: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html

Comment: dispatcher typically does not lead to an actual switching to another thread. In such scenarios,
     * the underlying implementation attempts to keep the execution on the same thread on a best-effort basis.

Comment: @SamsadCV Either way, from the perspective of the caller of `runBlocking`, the main thread is blocked from their use.

Answer (score -1):

Dispatcher typically does not lead to an actual switching to another thread. In such scenarios,
* the underlying implementation attempts to keep the execution on the same thread on a best-effort basis.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/3236/files